# Can't assign a value to a variable in a case statement in bash

Tags: bash, unix, variable-assignment

I just ran into a problem while I was trying to assign a value to a variable inside a case statement, here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":m:n:::" opt; do
  case $opt in
    n)

      echo "-n was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG " >&2
      case $OPTARG in 
        t)
            echo threads
            r=threads
            ;;
        p)
            echo processes
            r="something"
            ;;
        esac
      ;;
    m)
      echo "-m was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

echo $r
echo No thread/processes: $2 P/T: $4 IF: $5  OF: $6
```

I'd like to use the variable `$r` later, but I can't. When I try to print it using `echo` (as it is in my script), it does not return a thing.
I've been trying to spot my mistake but I couldn't.
There is a similar post that suggested to remove blank spaces before and after the `=`, but as you can see, there are no blank spaces in mine.

Here is what I get from the console when I run it:

```
$ ./friendfind -n 2 -m p IN OUT
-n was triggered, Parameter: 2 
-m was triggered, Parameter: p
No thread/processes: 2 P/T: p IF: IN OF: OUT
```

The purpose of the script was to run a c file with the option to run it with threads or processes, so it asks for the number of processes/threads you want to use, if you want to tu use processes or threads and the input and output file.

Comment: `r` will be set only if your invocation includes `-n t` or `-n p`. You have `-n 2`, so `r` will simply not be set. Perhaps you forgot a default case in the inner case statement? Otherwise, explain why you expect `r` to be set.

Comment: Also, what do you expect the three colons at the end of the options string to do?

Comment: Thank you so much, and sorry for asking such a dumb question. I was trying to get more than one argument but now I feel that is the wrong way too.

Comment: The purpose of the script was to run a c file with the option to run it with threads or processes, so it asks for the number of processes/threads you want to use, if you want to tu use processes or threads and the input anoutput file.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer. Now you can edit your question so the answer fits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were aiming at something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Print usage message:
usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 [-n N] [-t|-p] INPUT OUTPUT" >> /dev/stdout
}
# Set default values
n_threads=1  
use_threads=1
while getopts "n:pth" opt; do
  case $opt in
    n) n_threads=$OPTARG;;
    t) use_threads=1;;
    p) use_threads=0;;
    h) usage; exit 0;;
    *) usage; exit 1;;
  esac
done
# Get rid of scanned options
shift $((OPTIND-1))
if (($# != 2)); then usage; exit 1; fi
if ((use_threads)); then
  echo "Using $n_threads threads. IF: $1; OF: $2"
  # ...
else
  echo "Using $n_threads processes. IF: $1; OF: $2"
  # ...
fi
```

Here's some example invocations, including a couple of errors:

```
$ ./ff -p foo bar
Using 1 processes. IF: foo; OF: bar
$ ./ff foo bar
Using 1 threads. IF: foo; OF: bar
$ ./ff -n 7 foo bar
Using 7 threads. IF: foo; OF: bar
$ ./ff -n 7 -p foo bar
Using 7 processes. IF: foo; OF: bar
$ ./ff -p -n7 foo bar
Using 7 processes. IF: foo; OF: bar
$ ./ff -q -n7 foo bar
./ff: illegal option -- q
Usage: ./ff [-n N] [-t|-p] INPUT OUTPUT
# Note: The error message here could be more informative.
# Exercise left for the reader
$ ./ff -n 7 foo
Usage: ./ff [-n N] [-t|-p] INPUT OUTPUT
```